# Postgres - How to find text that contains a newline character using like

Tags: postgresql

I am querying a field of texts and want to extract the rows that contain newlines anywhere within the text using *Postgres*.

For example I would like to return the texts that look like the following:

```
row1 -> hello \nthere
row2 -> see you tomorrow\n
```

I tried using something like the following:

`select descr from description_tb where descr like '%\n%'`

However this won't work since \n probably needs to be escaped, but I can't figure out how to do it for my case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't need to be escaped as it already is escaped.  It needs to be un-escaped!

You can do this by prefacing the quote mark with an `E`.

```
select descr from description_tb where descr like E'%\n%'
```

Or you could just write a literal new line but there you may be at the mercy of how your client program conveys it:

```
select descr from description_tb where descr like '%
%'
```